# Constellation Detection

Tags: android-studio, opencv, kotlin

Helloooo guys !

I've started a project to write an algorithm that can recognize constellations in the northern hemisphere. But it can only recognize constellations on very easy pictures.

My objective being this:

[image: This is the input]

[image: This this the output]

```
private fun rotate(
        templateData: Array<Array<Array<String>>>,
        brightest_index: Int,
        second_brightest: Int
    ): Array<Array<DoubleArray>> {
        val userStarData: Array<DoubleArray> = CameraActivity.starArray
        val rotatedTemplates =
            Array(
                5
            ) {
                Array(
                    89
                ) { arrayOfNulls<String>(31) }
            }
        val x0: Double
        val y0: Double
        val x1: Double
        val y1: Double
        val dx: Double
        val dy: Double
        var angle = 0.0
        x0 = userStarData[brightest_index][0]
        y0 = userStarData[brightest_index][1]
        x1 = userStarData[second_brightest][0]
        y1 = userStarData[second_brightest][1]
        dx = x1 - x0
        dy = y1 - y0
        // Angle en Radians
        angle = Math.atan(dx / dy)
        Log.i(TAG, "Rotation angle: $angle")
        return rotateTemplates(templateData, angle)
    }

    /**
     * Cette fonction est appelée une fois que l'angle de rotation a été calculé, fait tourner les données du modèle.
     * @param templateData template de constellation
     * @param angle angle de rotation déterminé par rotateTemplate
     * @return
     */
    private fun rotateTemplates(
        templateData: Array<Array<Array<String>>>,
        angle: Double
    ): Array<Array<DoubleArray>> {
        val rotatedTemplates =
            Array(
                5
            ) { Array(89) { DoubleArray(31) } }
        var x: Double
        var y: Double
        var xprime: Double
        var yprime: Double
        // Pour chaque constellation :
        for (i in 0..85) {
            val numStars = templateData[0][i][1].toInt()
            for (j in 0 until numStars) {
                x = templateData[1][i][j].toDouble()
                y = templateData[2][i][j].toDouble()
                // Pour chaque x et y, analyser les valeurs, puis calculer les valeurs pivotées. Formules :
// x' = (x * cos(theta)) - (y * sin(theta))
// y' = (x * sin(theta)) + (y * cos(theta))
                xprime = x * Math.cos(angle) - y * Math.sin(angle)
                yprime = x * Math.sin(angle) + y * Math.cos(angle)
                // Échange des coordonnées x et y pour inverser les modèles afin qu'ils correspondent à la façon dont la caméra représente les blobs
                rotatedTemplates[1][i][j] = yprime
                rotatedTemplates[2][i][j] = xprime
            }
        }
        return rotatedTemplates
    }

    //cette fonction recherche dans les ensembles de données d'images et de modèles de l'utilisateur pour trouver une correspondance entre les données
//cette fonction recherche les correspondances en analysant chaque ensemble de triplets d'étoiles dans l'ensemble des données de l'image utilisateur
//regarder d'abord les deux premières étoiles du triplet pour déterminer l'échelle de leurs coordonnées et appliquer cette échelle au modèle considéré
//puis itérez sur l'ensemble de données de l'utilisateur pour chaque ensemble de triplets possibles, en vérifiant s'il y a une correspondance de distance
//dans une fenêtre de 10 % de la distance entre les étoiles correspondantes du modèle
//continuer d'itérer jusqu'à ce qu'un triplet soit trouvé
//puis itérez les données de l'utilisateur à partir de la troisième étoile du triplet pour trouver les autres étoiles de la constellation
    private fun findConstellationMatch(templateData: Array<Array<Array<String>>>): Array<Array<String>> {
        val userStarData: Array<DoubleArray> =
            CameraActivity.starArray //saisir un ensemble de données à partir d'une image de l'utilisateur provenant de l'activité de la caméra
        val match =
            Array(
                3
                ) { Array(31, {i -> ""}) }
//            ) { arrayOfNulls<String>(31) } //ce tableau contiendra les coordonnées de toutes les étoiles de la constellation identifiée
        var templateNumStars: Int
        for (i in 0..85)  //itérer à travers chacune des 89 constellations
        {
            templateNumStars = templateData[0][i][1].toInt()
            //itérer sur le jeu de données de l'image utilisateur pour l'index de la première étoile du triplet
            for (starOne in 0 until userStarData.size - 2) {
                val starOne_x = userStarData[starOne][0]
                //itérer sur le jeu de données de l'image utilisateur pour l'index de la seconde étoile du triplet
                for (starTwo in starOne + 1 until userStarData.size - 1) {
                    val rotatedTemplates =
                        rotate(templateData, starOne, starTwo)
                    val starTwo_x = userStarData[starTwo][0]
                    //itérer sur le jeu de données de l'image utilisateur pour l'index de la troisieme étoile du triplet
                    for (starThree in starTwo + 1 until userStarData.size) { // Échelle utilisant la distance entre les deux étoiles les plus brillantes, calculer les rapports.
                        val templateXDelta =
                            (rotatedTemplates[1][i][2] - rotatedTemplates[1][i][1]) / (rotatedTemplates[1][i][1] - rotatedTemplates[1][i][0])
                        val templateYDelta =
                            (rotatedTemplates[2][i][2] - rotatedTemplates[2][i][1]) / (rotatedTemplates[2][i][1] - rotatedTemplates[2][i][0])
                        val xDelta =
                            (userStarData[starThree][0] - userStarData[starTwo][0]) / (userStarData[starTwo][0] - userStarData[starOne][0])
                        val yDelta =
                            (userStarData[starThree][1] - userStarData[starTwo][1]) / (userStarData[starTwo][1] - userStarData[starOne][1])
                        //vérifier si une correspondance a été trouvée avec le jeu de triplés
                        if (templateNumStars <= userStarData.size && xDelta > templateXDelta * 0.9 && xDelta < templateXDelta * 1.1 && yDelta > templateYDelta * 0.9 && yDelta < templateYDelta * 1.1) {
                            Log.i(
                                TAG,
                                "Match le premier triplet de " + templateData[0][i][0]
                            )
                            //si une correspondance a été trouvée, enregistrer leurs coordonnées dans le tableau de correspondance [][] ainsi que le nom de la constellation identifiée
                            match[0][0] = templateData[0][i][0]
                            match[1][0] =
                                java.lang.Double.toString(userStarData[starOne][0])
                            match[2][0] =
                                java.lang.Double.toString(userStarData[starOne][1])
                            match[1][1] =
                                java.lang.Double.toString(userStarData[starTwo][0])
                            match[2][1] =
                                java.lang.Double.toString(userStarData[starTwo][1])
                            match[1][2] =
                                java.lang.Double.toString(userStarData[starThree][0])
                            match[2][2] =
                                java.lang.Double.toString(userStarData[starThree][1])
                            return match
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        // Si aucune correspondance n'a été trouvée, retournez un tableau vide..
        val res = Array(3) { Array(31, {i -> ""}) }
        return res
//        return Array(3) { arrayOfNulls<String>(31) }
    }
}
```

The database look like that :

[link to image of db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFHvc.png)

I don't know if the error comes from the image processing or from the algorithm itself.

Comment: What language is this? It's certainly not Java.

Comment: Yes my bad, I meant kotlin.